# Nested Array search in MongoDB/PyMongo while using aggregate

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to search for a keyword inside array of arrays in a Mongo document.

```
{
  "PRODUCT_NAME" : "Truffle Cake",

  "TAGS": [
            ["Cakes", 100],
            ["Flowers", 100],
       ]
}
```

Usually, I would do something like this and it would work.

```
db.collection.find( {"TAGS":{"$elemMatch":{ "$elemMatch": {"$in":['search_text']} } }} )
```

But now, I changed this query to an aggregate based query due to other requirements. I've tried $filter , $match but not able to replicate the above query exactly..

Can anyone convert the above code so that it can directly work with aggregate?
(I use PyMongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) uses the same query syntax as the query language (find), from the docs:

> The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax;

This means if you have a query that works in a "find", it will also work within a `$match` stage, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "TAGS": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "$in": [
              "Cakes"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Check this live on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w9eYm7KL6aV)

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Very similar question, I believe you could help with that as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727058/mongo-aggregate-match-condition-only-on-second-collection-but-provide-all-docu

Comment: sure, answered:)