# MongoDB Aggregate - Match condition only on second collection but provide all documents from the first

Tags: django, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Basically, I have 2 collections in my **MongoDB** database -> Books, Scores.

**Books**

```
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "100",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 1",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "abcd",
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "101",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 2",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "efgh",
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "102",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 3",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "ijkl",
}
```

---

**Scores**

```
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "100",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "kids",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : "6",
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "100",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Educational",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : "8",
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "101",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Kids",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : "6",
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "101",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Fantasy",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : "7",
}
```

---

**Expected output :**
Searching for all books with `BOOKS_CATEGORY="Kids"` and `BOOKS_SCORE=6``

```
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "100",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 1",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "abcd",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Kids",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : 6
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "101",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 2",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "efgh",
    "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Kids",
    "BOOK_SCORE" : 6
},
{
    "BOOK_ID" : "102",
    "BOOK_NAME" : "Book 3",
    "BOOK_DESC" : "ijkl",
}
```

Notice that, for all the books to which scores are available, they are appended. If a Book does not have any score associated, it still comes in the result.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried using `$lookup`

```
pipeline = [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                    "from": "Scores",
                    "pipeline":[
                        {
                            "$match" : {
                                "BOOK_CATEGORY" : "Kids",
                                "BOOK_SCORE" : "6",
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "localField": "BOOK_ID",
                    "foreignField": "BOOK_ID",
                    "as": "SCORES", 

                    },
                },
            ]
db.Books.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Also, by reading the `$lookup` subquery docs,(https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection)
I got the feeling that what I am expecting may not be possible.
Can anyone help me with executing such query? (I use PyMongo btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last two stages:

1. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document(s) with the new document(s) by merging the current document with the document which is the first document from the `SCORES` array.
2. `$unset` - Remove `SCORES` array.

```
db.Books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Scores",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "BOOK_CATEGORY": "Kids",
            "BOOK_SCORE": "6",
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "localField": "BOOK_ID",
      "foreignField": "BOOK_ID",
      "as": "SCORES"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $first: "$$ROOT.SCORES"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "SCORES"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oQtxQsSVEh3)

Comment: Is there a way to get null values to have a default value? For example - if a BOOK_SCORE is null, then have -1 in it's place for all the products? Like we have in addFields?

Comment: Did you mean something like this? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-E-ANb3EjKh). Maybe you can try to provide sample data and output for that case

Comment: Yes, that was it! On side note, how would you go about making an inner join while merging 2 collections.. EX- for the above question, for BOOK_SCORE=6 & BOOK_CATEGORY="Kids" , only 2 documents should result.

Comment: You need a `$match` stage to check whether `SCORES` array is not empty. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_kbgIkdwFAH). Meanwhile, I would suggest creating a new question as the answer designed based on the question and changing/adding requirements will make the question hard to keep track.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a conditional `$addFields`, if the `$lookup` value exists then populate the values, else use `$$REMOVE` to remove the field, like so:

```
db.Books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Scores",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "BOOK_CATEGORY": "kids",
            "BOOK_SCORE": "6"
          }
        }
      ],
      "localField": "BOOK_ID",
      "foreignField": "BOOK_ID",
      "as": "SCORES"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      SCORES: "$$REMOVE",
      "BOOK_SCORE": {
        $cond: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$SCORES",
                  0
                ]
              },
              false
            ]
          },
          {
            $getField: {
              field: "BOOK_SCORE",
              input: {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$SCORES",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      },
      "BOOK_CATEGORY": {
        $cond: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$SCORES",
                  0
                ]
              },
              false
            ]
          },
          {
            $getField: {
              field: "BOOK_CATEGORY",
              input: {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$SCORES",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/weQaJn9vtLt)

Comment: This answer was also very helpful! But, if there are 10 more fields, it becomes difficult to keep check on the fields.

Comment: you can do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_wMlV3dElRe) using `$replaceRoot` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up using. Thanks 